# Python Unicode and \xe2\x80\x98r\xe2\x80\x99 error

Tags: python, unicode, character-encoding

> Python version 3.5.2

So I have file output from `mitmproxy` called `enter code here`, and I want to read it using:

```
from shelljob import proc

g = proc.Group()
command = "tail -f -c +0 output_file | mitmdump -n -r - --set flow_detail=1 --showhost"
p = g.run (command)

def read_process():
    while g.is_pending():
        lines = g.readlines()
        for proc, line in lines:
            print ("data:" + str(line) + '\n\n')
```

and returning

```
data:b'tail: invalid number of lines: \xe2\x80\x98r\xe2\x80\x99\n'
```

but if I change command to `ping 127.0.0.1`, like:

```
from shelljob import proc

g = proc.Group()
command = "ping 127.0.0.1"
p = g.run (command)

def read_process():
    while g.is_pending():
        lines = g.readlines()
        for proc, line in lines:
            print ("data:" + str(line) + '\n\n')
```

and it works fine!. returning:

```
data:b'64 bytes from 127.0.0.1: icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=0.056 ms\n'
```

So what's the solution?

Comment: Have you tried adding ` # -*- coding: utf-8 -*-` at the top of your script file?

Comment: I already tried adding  # -- coding: utf-8 --, but same error @LISHITING

Comment: So, what eaxactly are you askinge here? Why your command `tail -f -c +0 output_file | mitmdump -n -r - --set flow_detail=1 --showhost` does not work as you expect and how to fix it? Because the encoding of the output does not seem as much of a problem for you as the question suggests from my point of view

Comment: @LISHITING That declaration only declares the encoding of the *source file*.  If the source file is all ASCII (as shown) it makes no difference.

Answer (score 0):

The data is returned in bytes, as indicated by the `b` in fron of the output.
You have to decode it to a string.

`print ("data:" + line.decode('utf-8') + '\n\n')`

Comment: Error again.. and returning `tail: invalid number of lines: ‘r’`

Comment: yes. that is an error that the command on the command line produces. It has nothing to do with python. Also, see metatoaster's answer regarding this

Answer (score 0):

I am pretty sure your command isn't being piped as you might expected when calling `g.run` - the arguments `-n -r` after `mitmdump` is somehow being passed to `tail`, thus running this:

```
$ tail -n -r
tail: invalid number of lines: ‘r’
```

Produce that error message you are seeing.

Now that you tell us what `g.run` actually is, looking at the [documentation](https://pythonhosted.org/shelljob/shelljob.html#shelljob.proc.Group.run) for the function we can see that it takes a `shell` argument which is passed to [`Popen`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen), which is the argument to enable the processing of shell commands.  To resolve this issue, you may try the following instead:

```
p = g.run(command, shell=True)
```

Comment: Oh sorry, I updated my code. I followed tutorial from: https://mortoray.com/2014/03/04/http-streaming-of-command-output-in-python-flask/#comment-29298

Comment: Does anything print on the screen when you run the command directly from the command line outside of Python?

Comment: Then it is working in the exact same way.  Are you sure `output_file` is being written with data? What does running `tail -f output_file` provide?

Comment: I'm sure there is data in `output_file`. If I change command to `tail -f -c +0 output_file` and change `shell=False`, it print binary text same as `tail -f output_file`..

Comment: Instead of piping to `mitmdump`, pipe to something neutral like `cat` and see if it works the same in the Python code as it would work in the command line.